# Inverse gamma posterior

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, prior, posterior

I am working on bayesian analysis and I have a normal likelihood function and an inverse gamma (IG) prior for the parameter $\lambda$.
I have the following posterior:
$$
\propto \frac{1}{\lambda^{\tilde \alpha +1}} \cdot \text{exp}\Biggl( -\frac{1}{2} \Biggl[\sum_{t=1}^T \frac{(\psi^2 + \Omega) \Delta t}{\Omega (2\gamma)^{-2} \psi^2} \lambda^2
 - 2 \sum_{t=1}^T \frac{(\psi^2 + \Omega)\left(R_t - \left(r - \frac{1}{2} h_{t-1} \right) \Delta t \right)}{\Omega \sqrt{h_{t-1}} (2\gamma)^{-2} \psi^2 } \lambda  
 + \frac{2 \psi \left(h_t - h_{t-1} - \left(\omega + (\beta + \alpha(1+ \gamma^2) -1)h_{t-1} \right)\Delta t\right)}{\Omega \alpha h_{t-1}(2\gamma)^{-1} \psi } \lambda\Biggr] - \frac{\tilde \beta} {\lambda}\Biggr)
$$

I can reduce it to:
$$\propto \frac{1}{\lambda^{\tilde \alpha +1 }} \cdot\text{exp} \left(-\frac{1}{2} \left(a_{\lambda} \lambda^2 - 2 b_{\lambda} \lambda\right)- \frac{\tilde \beta}{\lambda} \right)$$

Where $a_{\lambda}$ and $b_{\lambda}$ are defined as:
$$ a_{\lambda} \equiv \sum_{t=1}^T \frac{(\psi^2 + \Omega) \Delta t}{\Omega (2\gamma)^{-2} \psi^2}
$$

$$ b_{\lambda} \equiv \sum_{t=1}^T \frac{(\psi^2 + \Omega)\left(R_t - \left(r - \frac{1}{2} h_{t-1} \right) \Delta t \right)}{\Omega \sqrt{h_{t-1}} (2\gamma)^{-2} \psi^2 } 
 + \frac{2 \psi \left(h_t - h_{t-1} - \left(\omega + (\beta + \alpha(1+ \gamma^2) -1)h_{t-1} \right)\Delta t\right)}{\Omega \alpha h_{t-1}(2\gamma)^{-1} \psi }$$

I know this looks like an Inverse gamma density, but I dont know how to find the parameters of this distribution? If it was a normal distribution, we could do complete square, but that does not seem to work here.

Comment: If it was inverse gamma, how would it come to have terms like $\lambda^2$ in the exponent?

Comment: @Glen_b So this is a non-standard distribution?

Comment: What counts as standard and what counts as nonstandard?

Comment: @Glen_b Whether I have to use Gibbs or Metropolis Hastings for sampling from the distribution?

Comment: ... so if there's a way to generate from that distribution, it counts as standard?

Comment: @Glen_b I gues that is what I meant.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think this will be a [Inverse Gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Gaussian_distribution). You will need to play around with the terms inside the exponential.

Comment: @Greenparker That would have terms in the exponent of $\lambda$, constant and $1/\lambda$ while this has terms in the exponent of $\lambda^2,\lambda$ and $1/\lambda$

Comment: @Glen_b Yes, fair point. Not an Inverse Gaussian then.

Comment: @Glen_b than it is not of any standard distribution? Or I am wrong, what do you think it should be or what should we do?

Comment: It's not a distribution I recognize, but that's not your criterion for "standard" which was instead "can you generate values from it?" and indeed there are ways to do that. Note that you can write the density as the product of a Gaussian density and an inverse gamma density (which, presumably, is the same kind of product you started with) - you can separate out the first two terms in the exponent out and complete the square. As a result this has lighter tails than the inverse gamma. ... ctd

Comment: ctd ... You could for example generate it via accept-reject using an inverse-gamma proposal, which might not do too badly if the Gaussian didn't have a small standard deviation.  Greenparker's mention of the inverse Gaussian is interesting because it provides another potential majorizing function. (There are other possibilities for generating this within a Gibbs framework, of course.)

Comment: What do you mean by "for the parameter $\lambda$"? The symbols of the parameters of a Normal model are not uniquely set. From the Inverse Gamma prior can we safely deduce that this parameter is positive?

Comment: @Xi'an yes, it is safe to assume tha $\lambda$ is positive.